# How to give celery enough permission to run a root file without compromising security?

Tags: python, celery

I'm running the code below as part of a Celery task.

```
class HealthCheckIKEV2:
    async def report(self):
        try:
            client = RedisClient()
            proc1 = subprocess.Popen(
                ["sudo", "/usr/sbin/swanctl", "--list-sas"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE
            )
            proc2 = subprocess.Popen(
                ["grep", "INSTALLED"],
                stdin=proc1.stdout,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            )
            proc3 = subprocess.Popen(
                ["wc", "-l"],
                stdin=proc2.stdout,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                universal_newlines=True,
            )
            proc1.stdout.close()  # Allow proc1 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc2 exits.
            proc2.stdout.close()  # Allow proc2 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc3 exits.
            out, err = proc3.communicate()
            info = {
                "users": out.rstrip(),
                "timestamp": datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
            }
            client.conn.hset(settings.REDIS_VPN_SUBDOMAIN, mapping=info)
```

However Celery fails with the following error message:

```
Jun 13 08:46:42 de-vpn-1 sudo[2038]:   celery : user NOT in sudoers ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/admin/app ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/swanctl --list-sas
Jun 13 08:47:42 de-vpn-1 sudo[2045]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
```

This is because of this line where the subprocess has to run as sudo to be able to execute `/usr/sbin/swanctl`.

```
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(
                ["sudo", "/usr/sbin/swanctl", "--list-sas"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE
            )
```

What are my options here? Celery documentation says to not give the celery user root access. What can I do to adhere to best practices and yet get this task executed successfully?

One idea I had was to create a new group and add both `root` and `celery` users to that group. And change the permission of that file to that group. Sounds a bit hacky though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the `celery` user to the `sudoers` file with the only command allowed being the one needed. Use `visudo` and add these lines

```sh
celery all = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/swanctl --list-sas
```

The `NOPASSWD:` directive insures linux will not ask for a password.

**Note:** this gives anyone who can control this user this level of access

Comment: Thank you, that's a great answer. I applied that and had to remove sudo from subprocess and celery can then execute it.  However it still fails ```connecting to 'unix:///var/run/charon.vici' failed: Permission denied
Error: connecting to 'default' URI failed: Permission denied```. Do you know how I could give it additional access to `unix:///var/run/charon.vici`?

Comment: maybe try giving access sudo setfacl --modify user:celery :rwx /var/run/charon.vici. If this works please mark answered

Comment: I found a way: ```celery  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/swanctl```. This gives full access to swanctl and underlying dependencies.  But other commands like `sudo ls` aren't allowed.

Comment: this also gives it the ability to run all arguments possible with `swanctl`. This may be fine for your use case though

Answer (score 0):

I would simply set the [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) flag on `/usr/sbin/swanctl` and then run it from Celery without the need for sudo.

Comment: Would this open up a possible security hole depending on who owns `/usr/sbin/swanctl`?